# Django login only for registered user and on logout back to login page

Tags: python, authentication, django-urls, logout, django-2.0

I have created a login view in my project urls.py,

```
urlpatterns = [
 path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
]
```

login.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="\" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Till here it works fine I can see login page and login into it. But now I can login with any anonymous credentials and they can see the home page.
So how do I restrict it to registered user and then logout them.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `path('login/'...` stuff to `urls.py` it does nothign to access to home page. You will need to either forbid access to homepage explicitly by adding [login_required](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) to your view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Or you can use [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) for class based view. Or as another option you can use [django-stronghold](https://djangopackages.org/packages/p/django-stronghold/) package.

Comment: I had added that decorator before every view but problem is I can able to login with any random username and password and then logout it.
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
 return render(request, 'home.html', {})